# Polymorphism PApplet Processing NullPointerException

Tags: java, processing

I have an assignment where I have to display "gym machines" and their data through the PApplet processor. I need to use polymorphism and inheritance (a treadmill is a GymMachine, etc.). Each gym machine must have its own draw method. I just can't figure out how to avoid a NullPointerException.

This is the code in my "ProcessingExample.java" file, the code that will actually draw the images through a processor:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;

public class ProcessingExample extends PApplet {

  public long start_time;

  public static int canvas_x = 1200;
  public static int canvas_y = 800;

  TreadMill treadmill;
  Stepper stepper;
  Bicycle bicycle;

  public ProcessingExample(){
    start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  public void setup(){
    size(canvas_x, canvas_y);
    treadmill = new TreadMill();
    stepper = new Stepper();
    bicycle = new Bicycle();
  }

  public void draw(){
    // treadmill
    treadmill.draw();
  }
}
```

This is my GymMachine class, from which the treadmill will derive:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;

public class GymMachine extends PApplet {
  public long start_time;

  public static int canvas_x = 1200;
  public static int canvas_y = 800;

  public GymMachine(){
    start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  public void draw(){ // for now I am just trying to draw the background, a block of color on 1/3 of the canvas
    fill(83, 85, 171);
    rect(0, 0, canvas_x / 3, canvas_y);
  }
}
```

Here is my treadmill class just for the sake of clarity:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;

public class TreadMill extends GymMachine {
  private int angleOfInclination;
  private double mph;

  public TreadMill(){
    angleOfInclination = 1;
    mph = 1.0;
    image = "treadmill.png";
  }

  public TreadMill(int i, double m){
    if (i >= 1 && i <= 15){ // data validation
      angleOfInclination = i;
    }
    else { // else, defer to defaults
      angleOfInclination = 1;
    }

    if (m >= 1.0 && m <= 15.0){
      mph = m;
    }
    else {
      mph = 1.0;
    }
  }

  public void setAngleOfInclination(int i){
    if (i >= 1 && i <= 15){ // data validation
      this.angleOfInclination = i;
    }
  }

  public void setMPH(double m){
    if (m >= 1.0 && m <= 15.0){ // data validation
      this.mph = m;
    }
  }

  public long getCaloriesUsed(){
     return 20 *(long) mph + 15 * angleOfInclination;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return "Angle of inclination is " + angleOfInclination + " degrees; Speed is " + mph + " mph; Calories burned: " + this.getCaloriesUsed();
  }
}
```

For the past 5 hours, I haven't been able to figure out why `treadmill.draw()` complains a NullPointerException. I'm not quite sure what the `null` variable is. I have tried making ProcessingExample and GymMachine the same class, because I thought maybe it needed access to the "same canvas," but the problem then is that ProcessingExample keeps calling itself, since I need to create an instance of treadmill somewhere. I have also read that rather than making `GymMachine extend PApplet`, I could make the constructor take an argument of type `PApplet`, (i.e. `GymMachine(PApplet p){...})`, but then I cannot get `TreadMill` to derive from this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Only one class should extend the `PApplet` class.

Think of a `PApplet` as a whole sketch running in a window. You only want one window to show up, right? So you only want one `PApplet` class.

You don't want each `GymMachine` to show up in its own window. You want multiple `GymMachines` to be drawn in one window. So get rid of the `extends PApplet` on the `GymMachine` class.

After you do that, you'll get some compiler errors because the `GymMachine` class won't recognize functions like `fill()` or `rect()`. To fix this, you'll need to pass in an instance of the main sketch class (the class that does extend `PApplet`) into the secondary sketch class. The `this` keyword comes in handy for this.

Finally, you'll have to use the reference to the main `PApplet` sketch to call Processing functions. Here's an example:

```
public class MySketch extends PApplet{

  Thing thing = new Thing(this);

  public void draw(){
    thing.draw();
  }
}

public class Thing{
  PApplet mainSketch;

  public Thing(PApplet mainSketch){
    this.mainSketch = mainSketch;
  }

  public void draw(){
    mainSketch.ellipse(100, 100, 100, 100);
  }
}
```

See the **Calling Processing Functions From Non-Sketch Classes** section of [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java) for more info.